# Show that $p'(x_0) = {{4y_1 - 3y_0 - y_2} \over 2h}.$

Tags: numerical-methods

It was part of an bigger excercise to calculate the Newton polynomial

$$p(x) =y_0 + {{y_1 - y_0} \over h} (x-x_0) + (-2y_0 + 4y_1 - 2y_2)(x-x_0)(x-x_1).$$

Now, I need to show that

$$p'(x_0) = {{4y_1 - 3y_0 - y_2} \over 2h}.$$

But solving this by simplifying $p(x)$ seems way over the top, given the fact that this was an old exam question and that it would take too long. Does anyone see a trick to do this easier?

Answer (score 0):

Just compute of
$$
p(x)=y_0+\frac{y_1-y_0}h(x-x_0)+\frac{y_2-2y_1+y_0}{2h^2}(x-x_0)(x-x_1)
$$
the term-wise derivative
$$
p'(x)=\frac{y_1-y_0}h+\frac{y_2-2y_1+y_0}{2h^2}(2x-x_1-x_0)
$$
and evaluate at $x=x_0$.

Of course it is helpful to start with an interpolation formula that actually has $p(x_2)=y_2$.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible that my Interpolation formula is wrong then?

Comment: Why don't you check yourself what you get for $p(x_2)$?

Comment: Well, it's not $y_2$ at least. I should check the formula again then.

Comment: The way I see it, the formula doesn't even hold for $p(x_1) = y_1.$

Comment: No, that part is correct as $x_1-x_0=h$ and the third term has a zero factor.